# ASP returning a json array after sending email

Tags: asp-classic

I initially had a php mail script ready, but the server didn't have php, so I'm left with figuring out asp.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');


$mail             = new PHPMailer(); 

$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);


$mail->AddAddress('info@example.com','john');

$mail->Subject    = "A message from contact form";

$mail->MsgHTML($note);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $the_return = array('request'=>'failed','prompt'=>$prompt);
echo json_encode($the_return);
} else {
    $the_return = array('request'=>'success');
echo json_encode($the_return);
}


die();
?>
```

what is important here is to try and recreate the creation of a json array and encoding it. I'm going to be running this script through a jquery ajax call so I want to return these values back to the contact form.

Comment: What does the JSON output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP doen't have a built in JSON encode function.

You can write directly to the response or use something like http://code.google.com/p/aspjsonrpc/source/browse/trunk/ASP-JSON-RPC/jsonParser.asp

If you want something more simple and write directly:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Response.Write "{ ""request"": ""failed"", ""prompt"": """ & prompt & """ }"
```

Comment: Also I don't think that link is refering to something that will generate JSON just parse it.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones OK, the souce link was removed. I'll add another source.